# Are the rings of the functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_n\to\mathbb{Z}_n$ Noetherian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noetherian

I want to check which of the following rings are noetherian:

a) the ring of the functions  $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

b) the ring of the functions $\mathbb{Z}_n\to\mathbb{Z}_n$, $n>1$.

This is the first time I see these kind of rings and I don't know how to work with them.

Comment: Hint for (b): Are there infinitely many functions $\mathbb Z_n \to \mathbb Z_n$?

Comment: I know that there is only one kind of homomorphism ($\phi(x)=ax$, $a\in\mathbb{Z}_n$) so they are not infinite. But I do not think it is the same with functions in general.

Comment: @Vasilis much more directly: $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is finite, so the set of functions $\mathbb{Z}_n \to \mathbb{Z}_n$ (which is a subset of $\mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_n$) is therefore finite.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk wow, I guess the simplest thoughts are the hardest to make. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first case you can try the ideals generated by the characteristic functions over the sets $(-n,n)$. If I am not wrong that would give you an increasing chain of ideals which not stabilizes. For the second case, someone has given you a hint.